# Return statement not working inside Jquery get method

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

I have a function that finds the name of the user from the database, according to the input userID. But I am facing difficulty in returning the name.

```
function getName(userID){
     var user = { "username" : userID};
     var name;
     $.get("/getName",user,function(data,status){
         console.log(data);  //prints correct result
         return data;        //but returns undefined
     });
}
```

The returned value is always undefined. The calling function looks like this :

```
function init(){
     myid = "james123";
     myname = getName(myid);
     console.log(myname);     //always prints undefined
}
```

If I try to save the data received from the database in a variable, and return it later, like :

```
function getName(userID){
      var user = { "username" : userID};
      var name;
      $.get("/getName",user,function(data,status){
          console.log(data);
          name = data;
      });
      return name;
  }
```

This also doesn't work and I know because it is asynchronous. Any way to make this return work?

Comment: return `$.get` as well: `return $.get(...)`. You will get a promise, i guess, you can handle it inside `then` and `catch` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

The $.get is executed asynchronously so it needs a callback. You can do it like this:

```
function getName(userID, callback){
     var user = { "username" : userID};
     var name;
     $.get("/getName",user,function(data,status){
         console.log(data);  //prints correct result
         callback(data);        //but returns undefined
     });
}
```

and then:

```
function init(){
     myid = "james123";
     getName(myid, function(myname){
         console.log(myname); 
     });
}
```

Or with Promises you can:

```
function getName(userID){
     var user = { "username" : userID};
     var name;
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
         $.get("/getName",user,function(data,status){
             resolve(data);  //prints correct result
         });
     }
}
```

and then:

```
function init(){
     myid = "james123";
     getName(myid).then((myname)=>console.log(myname);
}
```

and with async:

```
async function init(){
     myid = "james123";
     myname = await getName(myid);
     console.log(myname);
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with requests via jQuery, can't we just return this call and handle further, without callback?

Comment: Yes, it did work but is there any easier and beautiful way? Thanks a lot

Comment: @CommercialSuicide the code returns before the get has completed, so what is returned is a promise ie something that will eventually do something but hasn't yet, you can either wait for the promise to complete or you can set a callback inside the function that will be called at the appropriate point, either way you'll be using a callback of some variety

Comment: @MikeTm that's right, thanks for clarification. As i thought, it's possible as in other cases without jQuery

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: Its great...thank you sir.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can used the lower level ajax method as this allows you to customise more of the settings for the call than the higher level `get` does

One of the settings lets you disable the async call i.e. force your code to stop and wait for the get to complete before continuing this looks like `async: false` and is used like this:

```
function getName(userId) {
   var user = { "username" : userID};
   var name;
   $.ajax({
      url: "/getName",
      data: user,
      type: "GET",
      async: false,
      success: function (data) {
          name = data;
      },
   });
   return name;
}
```

Comment: your answer is a little confused as you aren't explaining that the ajax function allows for greater configuration of the command or that the only thing actually important there is the `async: false`

Comment: Thanks for the edit @MikeT, I need more practice answering on StackOverflow.